# Break out of Angular Zone

Tags: angular, zone

Here is an application which has nothing to do with Angular.

`project.ts`

```
export class Project {

   private ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

   constructor(private canvas: HTMLCanvasElement){

      this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      requestAnimationFrame(this.render);

   }

   private render = (): void => {

      requestAnimationFrame(this.render);

   }

}
```

It is rather boring for sure, but it is bread and butter animation. In my case, I am computationally generating lines during render on a canvas with `canvasContext.stroke()` but that is irrelevant.

I also have another Angular component which will run this above application. There is no need to bloat this question with all of the boilerplate code for Angular Components, however in the end, I have a canvas and here, I am attempting to run **the whole project** outside of Angular Zone.

```
ngAfterViewInit(){

    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
        this.project = new Project(this.canvas);
    });

}
```

At this point, I would expect that, `Project` and in particular `requestAnimationFrame` of that project, has nothing to do with Angular Zone.

When I look at the Dev Tools. I see this.

[image: zone calls]

What is actually happening here?

1. Is my render method still running inside angular zone?
2. Why?
3. How is this resolved?

I am looking for either clarification that I misunderstand dev tools, or that what I want to do isn't possible (yet).

Thanks for reading.